# ViewModels, XML and Wizards

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-5

I am using MVC3, Razor and EF5.

I have now realised that using a ViewModel for each page in a Wizard is a good idea, especially when you need to validate part of a record. I also need to save after each page submit. The Domain model has no validation annotations.

However I have now thought of a better/worse idea???!!! Ultimately I will be generating XML from the DB to put this record into a report. Therefore it could be possible/advisable to have a ViewModel with explicit column names and a domaim Model with just the XML field that all the ViewModel Property data goes into. Thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the actual practical problem you are experiencing? The question marks in your question don't reveal anything and your title is missing one.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. 1) Since I could store my data as XML, I am wondering whether the use of distinct ViewModels will enable me to validate the View accurately? If I just exposed the XML(from the domain model) to the View then I believe this validation would be more difficult. This is why at present I am not using XML field types in the domain model. I think the answer is yes. However I am still trying to work out how the the data is saved to the DB, when a ViewModel is saved. I guess there is a link up with the Domain POCO entity somewhere?

Comment: Since XML is meant for storage / exchange, I'd think it would just make the ViewModels more complex. I'd think you could write code that turns your ViewModels into XML at the end.

Comment: Not sure why my question has got a -1. If it is for clarity, then apologies. I would like to close this now, so Tom if you would like to put up an answer rather than a comment then I will award. Many thanks.

Comment: Infact I have now decided to use XML to creation of a document which I can render at a later date using XSLT. I will then persist this XML via the DB.

Comment: I would like to close this, so if you could put an answer in where I can mark it then that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since XML is meant for storage / exchange, I'd think it would just make the ViewModels more complex. I'd think you could write code that turns your ViewModels into XML at the end.